# Unhandled exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format When launching to iphone x on unreal engine 4.23

Tags: unreal-engine4

After following several guides on launching to ios I still cannot get it working. I have tried an empty project, the ar kit sample and the face ar sample to no avail. This is the error I'm getting:

LogPlayLevel: BUILD COMMAND STARTED LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Build Task, Time: 5.581737 LogPlayLevel: Running: mono "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.23/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe" AR IOS Development -Project=/Users/dondoo/Desktop/AR/AR.uproject /Users/dondoo/Desktop/AR/AR.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles -remoteini="/Users/dondoo/Desktop/AR" -skipdeploy -ini:Game:[/Script/UnrealEd.ProjectPackagingSettings]:BlueprintNativizationMethod=Di sabled -Manifest=/Users/dondoo/Desktop/AR/Intermediate/Build/Manifest.xml -NoHotReload -log="/Users/dondoo/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-AR-IOS-Development.txt" LogPlayLevel: Compiling against OS Version 12.0 [minimum allowed at runtime] LogPlayLevel: Error: ERROR: Unhandled exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. LogPlayLevel: at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) [0x0001a] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at System.Number.ParseSingle (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00071] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at System.Single.Parse (System.String s) [0x0001a] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyIOSTargetRules.get_RuntimeVersion () [0x00010] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.IOSPlatform.SetUpEnvironment (UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyTargetRules Target, UnrealBuildTool.CppCompileEnvironment CompileEnvironment, UnrealBuildTool.LinkEnvironment LinkEnvironment) [0x00226] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.SetupGlobalEnvironment (UnrealBuildTool.UEToolChain ToolChain, UnrealBuildTool.CppCompileEnvironment GlobalCompileEnvironment, UnrealBuildTool.LinkEnvironment GlobalLinkEnvironment) [0x00bc8] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.UEBuildTarget.Build (UnrealBuildTool.BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, UnrealBuildTool.ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, System.Boolean bIsAssemblingBuild, Tools.DotNETCommon.FileReference SingleFileToCompile) [0x00061] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.CreateMakefile (UnrealBuildTool.BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, UnrealBuildTool.TargetDescriptor TargetDescriptor, UnrealBuildTool.ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet) [0x00141] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Build (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] TargetDescriptors, UnrealBuildTool.BuildConfiguration BuildConfiguration, UnrealBuildTool.ISourceFileWorkingSet WorkingSet, UnrealBuildTool.BuildOptions Options, Tools.DotNETCommon.FileReference WriteOutdatedActionsFile) [0x0001a] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.BuildMode.Execute (Tools.DotNETCommon.CommandLineArguments Arguments) [0x002cc] in :0 LogPlayLevel: at UnrealBuildTool.UnrealBuildTool.Main (System.String[] ArgumentsArray) [0x00291] in :0 LogPlayLevel: Took 30,190432s to run mono, ExitCode=5 LogPlayLevel: UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (/Users/dondoo/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-AR-IOS-Development.txt) LogPlayLevel: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5) LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Build Task, Time: 29.662970 LogPlayLevel: Error: RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully. PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Unknown Error

I have a valid provisioning profile and certificate and apple developer account, working on a macbook pro trying to launch to an iphone x.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of error is in converting ios version from string to float disregarding language locale. "11.0" dot(".") is the problem

**ue4_23_0\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Platform\IOS\UEBuildIOS.cs**

```
...
//line 143
public float RuntimeVersion
{
    get { return float.Parse(Inner.ProjectSettings.RuntimeVersion); }
}
...
//line 368
public virtual string RuntimeVersion
{
    get
    {
        switch (MinimumIOSVersion)
        {
            case "IOS_11":
                return "11.0";
            case "IOS_12":
                return "12.0";
            default:
                return "11.0";
        }
    }
}
...
```

**Solution** (not best) add locale to parse

```
...
//line 10
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Globalization; // <- Add this
...
//line 143
public float RuntimeVersion
{
    get { return float.Parse(Inner.ProjectSettings.RuntimeVersion, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat); }
}
...
```

Or setup locale of system to use dot(".") as decimal separator